# Having an abstract class that defines a primary constructor variable with a default value, how can we set that immutable value from a subclass

Tags: kotlin

Given an abstract class:

```
abstract class SuperClass(val someVal: String = "defaultValue") : SomeSuperClass
```

I want the implementing subclass to have two constructors, one that wouldn't set `someVal`, thus relying on the `"defaultValue"`, another one that sets a different `someVal`, that is to say, `val sc = SubClass()` and `val sc2 = SubClass("anotherVal")`

I have tryied with:

```
class SubClass() : SuperClass() {
    constructor(someVal: String) : this(someVal)
```

But the compiler complains:

```
Error:(5, 37) Kotlin: There's a cycle in the delegation calls chain
```

How can I implement it keeping `someVal` immutable? A solution like the following is not valid since it would be mutable:

```
abstract class SuperClass(var someVal: String = "defaultValue") : SomeSuperClass 


class SubClass() : SuperClass() {
    constructor(someVal: String) : this() {
        super.someVal = someVal
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you omit the primary constructor you can do this:

```
class SubClass : SuperClass {
    constructor(someVal: String): super(someVal)
    constructor(): super()
}
```